# Does the Torah give instructions as to whose advice we listen to?

Tags: halacha

Of course Aseh l'kha rav uk'neh l'kha haver, but how do we discern good advice from the latter group from ones that are just not useful?

Comment: The Torah expects us to use common sense.

Comment: Emunas Chachomim

Comment: Where does the Torah say to follow the advice of your friends?

Comment: The phones of Ravs' ought to be really busy then.

Comment: @KennyXiong Trust me, they are.